# Mock DbContext.Entry function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit, moq

While Unit Testing, I have Mocked the repository class and want to unit test the Update method which is having below two line of code:

```
_dIContext.Entry(originalModel).CurrentValues.SetValues(processModel);
_dIContext.Entry(originalModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

at first line I am getting NullReferenceException.

Below is my SetUp method of Unit test class:

```
_mockContext = new Mock<ContextClass>(null);
processModels = CreateProcessModelList();
mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<ProcessModel>>();
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<ProcessModel>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(processModels.AsQueryable().Provider);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<ProcessModel>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(processModels.AsQueryable().Expression);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<ProcessModel>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(processModels.AsQueryable().ElementType);
mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<ProcessModel>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(processModels.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());
_mockContext.Setup(x => x.ProcessModels).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
_repository = new ProcessRepository(_mockContext.Object);
```

Can anyone correct me if my code is wrong?

Comment: Lools like you're not setting up dbcontext.entry etc. Any reason you're not just using an in memory provider?

Comment: Nope, not specific reason. In-Memory is running well when I tried, but suggestion from team member to do it like that.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in the repo with the dbcontext? E.g., save changes?

Comment: No sir, the code given is all about.